# Move Hyper-V storage (without making a copy)

Tags: hyper-v

Is there any method that will allow me to move the virtual disks on a Hyper-V VM that doesn't result in a temporary copy being made?

I have a VM, that is powered off, and is a Hyper-V replica.  I want to move one of the virtual hard disks from one folder to another.  The challenge is that the VHD is 1TB, and the underlying storage only has ~900GB free.  If it wasn't a Hyper-V replica I would just move the VHD on the filesystem, and edit the Virtual machine configuration.  I already tried that, but changing the storage configuration doesn't seem to be permitted for a replica.

I don't see any obvious ways to accomplish this using either the GUI, or the Powershell `Move-VMStorage` command.

Answer (score 2):

Since the VM is not running, just `CUT` and `PASTE` needed VHDX between the folders and then map the drive in the VM settings using a new path.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question. This is a hyper-v replica.  The GUI will not permit you to modify the path directly.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it. Have you tried to compact virtual hard disk (in case if it dynamic)? In theory, it should give you an additional space to move this disk using Hyper-V built-in "Move" operation. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708394(v=ws.10).aspx